# Phaser 3 Tweens with changing variable value

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm building an HTML5 game with Phaser 3. I have a counter tween that I add to the scene upon a certain if condition being met on click of a game object. (It is a text value that flashes red if the card's maximum stat value is lower than the player's value of that stat.)

First, I set the variable based on which card was clicked:

```
if (this == action1_card) {
                action = action1
                energy_cost = action1_energy_cost
                max_suspicion = action1_suspicion_threshold
                selected_card = action1_card_selected
} else if (this == action2_card) {
                action = action2
                energy_cost = action2_energy_cost
                max_suspicion = action2_suspicion_threshold
                selected_card = action2_card_selected
}
```

Once I have the values I want (max suspicion is the relevant variable in this case), I then apply the flashing color animation to it if the condition is met.

```
if (action.suspicion_threshold < game_data.player.stats.suspicion) {
    t.tweens.addCounter({
        from: 0,
        to: 100,
        duration: 250,
        repeat: 1,
        yoyo: true,
        ease: Phaser.Math.Easing.Sine.InOut,
        onUpdate: function(tween) {
            const value = Math.floor(tween.getValue());
            const colorObject = Phaser.Display.Color.Interpolate.ColorWithColor(
                                Phaser.Display.Color.ValueToColor('#000000'),
                                Phaser.Display.Color.ValueToColor('#FF0000'),
                                100,
                                value
                            )
            const color = Phaser.Display.Color.RGBToString(colorObject.r, colorObject.g, colorObject.b)
            max_suspicion.setColor(color);
    }
});
```

The issue is that, if I was to click on card 1 and then card 2 before the animation was finished on card 1, the animation from card 1's text would resume on card 2. This makes sense, as the variable "max_suspicion" was reassigned to the text object on card 2, and the tween's onUpdate function is continuing as it should.

**How do I either:**

**1)** prevent this from being reassigned (e.g. setting max_suspicion to permanently represent card 1's text object for the scope of the tween)

*or*

**2)** reset card 1's value to it's original color and end the tween prematurely so it doesn't carry over to card 2?

I will gladly clarify anything as needed. Thank you so much for any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your code, what the best solution is. *(and ofcourse the desired gameplay)*
I personally would put the **tween** in a variable:

```
  this.mytween = scene.tweens.addCounter(...);
```

and stop it on click before i do anything else

```
  if(this.mytween) {// just checking if it exists
      this.mytween.stop();
      ... // may be reset the color 
  }
```